# Stop "explorer" process completely using PowerShell

Tags: windows-7, powershell

Greeting,
I'm trying to stop "explorer" process using power-shell command:

```
Stop-Process -ProcessName explorer -Force
```

the problem with that line, it will stop the process but it will run again automatically so it just restarting the process not stopping it.

Please advice me how to stop "explorer" process completely  using power-shell

Regards,

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do this ( though I don't know why you wouldn't want explorer to come back):

```
taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe
```

Comment: I wonder what the difference is... Looks like there is a registry key that controls the behavior of explorer.exe when it crashes unexpectedly [AutoRestartShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc939703.aspx).

Comment: This answer can be problematic on servers.  You may want to kill your own process to change some things before your profile is reloaded, but you may not want to affect other users.  Which this will do.

Answer (score 7):

Set the AutoRestartShell DWord value to 0 before you kill explorer

```
PS> Set-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" -Name AutoRestartShell -Value 0
PS> Stop-Process -ProcessName explorer -Force
```

Comment: I didn't knew about that registry key, nice.

Answer (score 1):

Many years later but thanks for the quick tip.

just an FYI in case someone comes across this later like I did

In my case I don't want explorer to restart automatically because I want to reload the profile using:

```
Start-Process -ProcessName explorer -LoadUserProfile
```

OR load a new set of environment variables

```
Start-Process -ProcessName explorer -UseNewEnvironment
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
Stop-Process -Name explorer -Force
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1.0
Stop-Process -Name explorer -Force
```

This worked for me